# display failed pods from kubectl output

Tags: kubernetes, grep

I want to write a wrapper on `kubectl` to display only failed pods which means it should only display items whose Ready column values are not the same (i.e `0/1, 0/2, 1/2, 2/3,` etc.)

```
$ kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE       NAME                                        READY     STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
default         pod-with-sidecar                            1/2       ErrImagePull       0          39s
kube-system     calico-node-chcqq                           2/2       Running            2          7d
kube-system     calico-policy-controller-6449789dd6-z5t5j   1/1       Running            0          7d
kube-system     etcd                                        1/1       Running            0          7d
kube-system     kube-apiserver                              1/1       Running            2          7d
kube-system     kube-controller-manager                     1/1       Running            0          7d
kube-system     kube-dns-5c76d6bddb-8zhmq                   3/3       Running            1          7d
kube-system     kube-proxy-xq8j6                            1/1       Running            0          7d
kube-system     kube-scheduler-                             1/1       Running            0          7d
kube-system     tiller-deploy-5b7cb9cfd7-j725s              1/1       Running            0          7d
my-system       glusterfs-brick-0                           0/2       Pending            0          3m
my-system       sticky-scheduler-6d968f8d74-xvjqn           0/1       ImagePullBackOff   0          4m
```

so from the above output i want to print these failed pods

```
NAMESPACE       NAME                                        READY     STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
default         pod-with-sidecar                            1/2       ErrImagePull       0          4m
my-system       glusterfs-brick-0                           0/2       Pending            0          56s
my-system       sticky-scheduler-6d968f8d74-xvjqn           0/1       ImagePullBackOff   0          8m
```

This works!

```
$ kubectl get pods --all-namespaces | grep -vE '1/1|2/2|3/3'

NAMESPACE       NAME                                        READY     STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
default         pod-with-sidecar                            1/2       ErrImagePull       0          4m
my-system       glusterfs-brick-0                           0/2       Pending            0          56s
my-system       sticky-scheduler-6d968f8d74-xvjqn           0/1       ImagePullBackOff   0          8m
```

But it won't work if i have `2/4,0/4,0/5,0/6` etc in the `Ready` column, what can i do with `grep -vE '1/1|2/2|3/3'` to make it work for all such cases

Reference: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/49387

Comment: `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces | grep -v "Running"`?

Comment: i think `STATUS` won't always be `Running` if the pods are ready

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With GNU grep:

```
 | grep -Ev '([0-9]+)/\1'
```

Output:

```
NAMESPACE       NAME                                        READY     STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
default         pod-with-sidecar                            1/2       ErrImagePull       0          39s
my-system       glusterfs-brick-0                           0/2       Pending            0          3m
my-system       sticky-scheduler-6d968f8d74-xvjqn           0/1       ImagePullBackOff   0          4m
```

Answer (score 11):

You can do it by using `--field-selector`:

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces --field-selector=status.phase!=Running
```

[Source](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/49387#issuecomment-346746104)

Comment: that won't show pods if you have `CrashLoopBackOff`

Comment: I still see Succeeded jobs or completed and can't find out how to attach multiple field selectors like != Running|Completed

Comment: @Flowkap you can use `,` to separate field selector values eg: `kubectl get pods --field-selector=status.phase!=Running,status.phase!=Succeeded --all-namespaces`

Comment: @Bad_Coder I did find out in the meantime and totally forgot about this post but thanks anyway! Hope someone else also finds this useful :)

Comment: Unfortunatelly that does not work and returns "No resources found."

Kubectl GitVersion:"v1.15.3", Kubernetes 1.19.1

Answer (score 0):

This works.

```
kubectl get pods -A | gawk '!/(Running|Succeeded)/'
```

Output:

```
NAMESPACE           NAME                                                                 READY   STATUS             RESTARTS           AGE
vmware-system-csi   vsphere-csi-controller-856984d4c7-cx5x2                              6/7     Error              66 (7m12s ago)     4h9m
vmware-system-csi   vsphere-csi-controller-856984d4c7-hx965                              6/7     CrashLoopBackOff   72 (5s ago)        4h9m
```