# Check failed pods logs in a Kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes

I have a Kubernetes cluster, in which different pods are running in different namespaces. How do I know if any pod failed?

Is there any single command to check the failed pod list or restated pod list?

And reason for the restart(logs)?

Answer (score 4):

Depends if you want to have detailed information or you just want to check a few last failed pods.

I would recommend you to read about [Logging Architecture](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/).

In case you would like to have this detailed information you should use 3rd party software, as its described in Kubernetes Documentation - [Logging Using Elasticsearch and Kibana](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/logging-elasticsearch-kibana/) or another one [FluentD](https://www.fluentd.org/).

If you are using Cloud environment you can use Integrated with `Cloud Logging` tools (i.e. in `Google Cloud Platform` you can use `Stackdriver`).

In case you want to check logs to find reason why pod failed, it's good described in K8s docs [Debug Running Pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-running-pod/).

> If you want to get logs from specific pod

```
$ kubectl logs ${POD_NAME} -n {NAMESPACE}
```

> First, look at the logs of the affected container:

```
$ kubectl logs ${POD_NAME} ${CONTAINER_NAME}
```

> If your container has previously crashed, you can access the previous container's crash log with:

```
$ kubectl logs --previous ${POD_NAME} ${CONTAINER_NAME}
```

Additional information you can obtain using

```
$ kubectl get events -o wide --all-namespaces | grep <your condition>
```

Similar question was posted in [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56673619/display-failed-pods-from-kubectl-output), you can check if for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the times, the reason for app failure is printed in the lasting logs of the previous pod. You can see them by simply putting `--previous` flag along with your `kubectl logs ...` cmd.

Answer (score -1):

This'll work: `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces |  | grep -Ev '([0-9]+)/\1'`

Also, [Lens](https://k8slens.dev/) is pretty good in these situations.